# Can I use Asus Transformer power supply and dock as with regular laptop?

Tags: battery, charging, docking-station

I couldn't find this information in all reviews, so I am asking here about it -- I would like to get such experience with Assus Transformer:

1. I put everything together -- I plug power supply into the dock, I put tablet part into dock
2. Tablet part gets power from AC outlet, not from battery
3. I need to go, I pull out tablet from dock, I leave dock and power supply on desk
4. Tablet part works on its own battery
5. I get back home, and cycle repeats -- (1)

The crucial part is, I don't charge tablet directly, but indirectly, via dock, which itself is powered with power supply -- of course this is my wish, **the question is** -- is it actually possible with Asus Transformer?

Comment: The Transformer has a port that specifically connects to the dock?  I.e., it doesn't connect to the dock via USB?

Comment: Yes I know that, but can I plug in power supply into the dock, instead of tablet? All pictures and movies shows Transformer completely unplugged.

Comment: I'm not making statements, I'm asking questions. Note the questions marks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Power adapter can be plugged into tablet or dock.  It is possible to charge the tablet from the dock while the dock is being charged, remove the tablet, use tablet, return to dock for charging.
Hope this helps
Pete

Comment: Not true. I left my Transformer on the docking station all night plugged in and then took it to work. By the time I got there (max of 1 hour) it was dead and would not even turn on. The tablet was dead, the docking station was charged. What good is that if it won't charge the tablet?